# Adding a basic date format to a Batch File in Embedded xp

Tags: date, batch-file, backup

I am looking into modifying some code to add a date format to a batch file, this is the code we are using and it is on a Windows XP embedded machine

The date format can be as simple as 16012015

The file saves to the D drive then copies to a USB drive if we have one in, the storage on the PC is only small which is why we delete the file every time we backup

```
REM #### Creation of the ZIP file ####

Del %BackupPath%\%ZipName%
7z a -tzip %BackupPath%\%ZipName% %BackupPath%\Backup\



REM #### Copy to USB ####

IF EXIST E: (echo Copie sur disque E:
             copy %BackupPath%\%ZipName% E: /y )
IF EXIST F: (echo Copie sur disque F:
             copy %BackupPath%\%ZipName% F: /y )
IF EXIST G: (echo Copie sur disque G:
             copy %BackupPath%\%ZipName% G: /y )
IF EXIST H: (echo Copie sur disque H:
             copy %BackupPath%\%ZipName% H: /y )
IF EXIST I: (echo Copie sur disque I:
             copy %BackupPath%\%ZipName% I: /y )
```

Comment: If you just want to prevent the deletion of the Backup.zip file by appending the date to the file name?  If so, then add this before the set Zipname line: `for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ('"WMIC OS Get LocalDateTime /Value 2>nul"') do set "ISODATE=%%~A"` and change the set Zipname line to: `set "ZipName=%ISODATE:~0,8%_Backup.zip"`  This will make **20150116_Backup.zip**

Comment: here are some ways to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to keep the existing file on the PC as space is limited, but I do want to keep it on the USB drive which is why I need a date format so that it wont over write that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the date format and you're happy with the format used by `%DATE%` then something as simple as this should work:

```
REM Remove slashes and spaces from the date:
set d=%date:/=%
set d=%d: =%
set NewZipName=Backup-%d%.zip
```

On my PC `%DATE%` returns `Thu 01/15/2015` so that's why I'm removing the `/` and space above to produce a NewZipName of 'Backup-Thu01152015.zip', but in your case you may have to remove different characters according to your region settings date format...

then and at the end `copy %BackupPath%\%ZipName% G:\%NewZipName% /y`

Comment: I have tried the above code and added it to my file but id does not copy the file to my USB drive at all, no file and no date

Answer (score 3):

I find it best to have timestamps in YYYYMMDD format so that they will sort chronologically.

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7 delims=/:. " %%a in (`echo %DATE% %TIME%`) do set NOW=%%d%%b%%c_%%e%%f%%g
@echo now: %NOW%
set NewZipName=Backup-%NOW%.zip
```

This will print out a date in YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS format. Example output: `20150115_165438`